# accepting both upper and lower cases in prompts in javascript

Tags: javascript, case-sensitive, prompt

first time posting!

I did some digging around and couldn't find information on what I'm trying to achieve (sorry not the most advance javascript guy).

use case: prompt user a question, accept answer from user, weigh users' answer to cases, return a result

problem: since javascript is case sensitive, im trying to learn how to accept both upper case and lower case in the prompt without using too many repetitive cases (ie. switch)

Below is a simple piece of code that I'm constructing to see if I can achieve the use case (obviously it's not working though lol hence this question), thanks for the help in advance!

```
var jacketColor = function(x){
var x = prompt("color"?);
x===x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase||x===x.substring(0,1).toLowerCase)
};
}
var result;

switch (jacketColor) {

case "black":
    result = "pay $300";
break;

case "brown":
result = "Pay $200";  
break;

case "green":
result = "Pay $5";
break;

default:
result = "This color does not match my eyes!";
}
```

Comment: There's a `.toLowerCase()` function for String objects

Comment: Your code is not working because it full of compilation errors, among other things.

Comment: I caught the mistakes, thank you pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code should look something like that:

```
function whatColor() {
  var x = prompt("color?");
  return x.toLowerCase();
}

var result;
var jacketColor = whatColor();

switch (jacketColor) {
  case "black":
    result = "pay $300";
    break;
  case "brown":
    result = "Pay $200";  
    break;
  case "green":
    result = "Pay $5";
    break;
  default:
    result = "This color does not match my eyes!";
}
```

Comment: Just so I understand this fully.  I:
1. declared a function and changes the users' answer to lowercase without specifying which letter
2. declared the variable jacketColor to equate to the whatColor function

am i understanding this correctly?